# Give some examples using "food, cuisine, dish, menu and ingredient"

Tags: expressions, differences, sentence, example

I have troubles using some words about food and I cannot feel the subtle differences of their usage. I'd like to get some help with examples using these various words.

- Food
- Cuisine
- dishes
- menu
- meal
- grocery
- ingredient
- nutrition
- drink
- beverage

Comment: uhm, what are you trying to do ?

Comment: "Cuisine" is a hoity-toity way to say "food".  The others you can look up.

Comment: @HotLicks  Hoity-toity sounds British.  Shouldn't a kentuckian say "highfalutin" ? :-)

Comment: @Centaurus - Nah, that's Tennessean.  Besides which, I'm more Minnesotan, and for Minnesotans even "highfalutin" is too highfalutin.

Comment: This is a general reference question *and* it's too broad. You should explain what you find confusing with the words *food* and *cuisine*. Are you comparing the two? Are you wondering what differences, if any, there are between **The food in this restaurant is simple** , or **French cuisine is fairly simple** and **The French dishes are simple**? (For example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, go to Google Books

http://books.google.com/

type the words or expressions related to your interests (for the latter, put them in quote marks " ") in the search box, press Search, and thousands of examples will be at your fingertips:-))

Say

[**ingredients "korean cuisine"**](https://www.google.com/search?q=ingredients%20korean%20cuisine&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=ingredients%20%22korean%20cuisine%22)

will give you books such as

> [Traditions of South Korean Cooking: Learning the Basic ...](https://books.google.com/books?id=6XdDBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT4&dq=ingredients%20%22korean%20cuisine%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UUwsVdyBF9bbsATz7YGQCg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=ingredients%20%22korean%20cuisine%22&f=false) Martha
>   Stone - 2014
>
> Learning the Basic Techniques and Recipes of the South Korean Cuisine
>   Martha Stone ... With these physical conditions, Korean cuisine has
>   developed over the centuries to specifically cater to the country's
>   climate and geography.

Click on the links and have a look at the books.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give it my best. The examples below are not the only interpretation, but it should be common.

> **Food** - anything that you can eat
>    **Cuisine** - fancy word for food, usually mentioned together with nationality (e.g. Korean cuisine)
>
> **Dish(es)** - Food served on a dish/plate usually well prepared
>       **Menu** - list of every available dish in a restaurant
>
> **Meal** - the whole food package - food and drink together (think happy meal from McDonald's)
>
> **Grocery** - vegetables
>
> **Ingredient** - components which you make together to make some dish/food (e.g. spices, vegetables, meat, etc.)
>
> **Nutrition** - everything that your body really needs, think healthy food and vitamins
>
> **Drink** - liquid that you actually drink, but usually alcoholic (doesn't have to be)
>   **Beverage** - generic name for any refreshing liquid (usually non-alcoholic)